# Node one async call slows another in parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, dependencies

For over a year we've seen interesting patterns that don't always rear themselves but on occasion repeat and we've never been able to figure out why and I'm hoping someone can make sense of it. It may be our approach, it may be the environment (node 8.x & koa), it may be a number of things.

We make two async calls in parallel to our dependencies using the `request-promise` module.

Simplified code of a single api dependency:

```
const httpRequest = require("request-promise");

module.exports = function (url) {
    const requestOptions = { 
        uri: ...,
        json: true,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }

    return httpRequest(requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
            status = response.statusCode;
            tmDiff = moment().diff(tmStart);

            return createResponseObject({
                status,
                payload: response.body,
            })
        })
        .catch(err => { .... };
    });

};
```

Parallel calls:

```
const apiResponses = yield {
    api1: foo(ctx, route),
    api2: bar(ctx)
};
```

Yet we've seen situations in our response time charts where if 1 is slow, latency seems to follow the other separate service. It doesn't matter what services they are, the pattern has been noticed across > 5 services that may be called in parallel. Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing the supposed latency?

[image]

Comment: If the latency is caused by a temporarily slowed network connection, then it would be logical to expect both parallel requests to feel that same effect.  `ping` or `tracert` during the slowdown might give you useful diagnostics to see if it's a general transport issue.  If your node.js server (which runs Javascript single threaded) was momentarily busy doing something else with the CPU (serving another request, garbage collecting, etc...), then that would affect the apparent responsiveness of API calls just because it took a moment for node.js to get around to processing the waiting responses.

Comment: While this seems logical, you're suggesting that one monitors the graphs 24/7 until that brief moment of a latency spike to SSH into a remote box and conduct a tracert. Our graphs also show no CPU spike at this time. Not to say your response isn't a potential answer, but is there not a more automated way to make such determinations?
Thank you.

Comment: There are tools that monitor the responsiveness of your own http server on a continual basis (you can set whatever monitoring interval you want).  If you have a CPU-hog somewhere, those tools would show a similar lag in responsiveness.  There are also tools that monitor the health of your network connection which would also show a connectivity glitch.  These are the types of monitoring tools that people whose job it is to maintain a healthy server farm might use.  I don't have a name handy for either one, but you can presumably find such tools by searching.

Comment: Thank you. I'd mark your first comment as the answer but it wasn't posted as such for me to mark as the answer.

Comment: OK, I put my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the latency is caused by a temporarily slowed network connection, then it would be logical to expect both parallel requests to feel that same effect. `ping` or `tracert` during the slowdown might give you useful diagnostics to see if it's a general transport issue. If your node.js server (which runs Javascript single threaded) was momentarily busy doing something else with the CPU (serving another request, garbage collecting, etc...), then that would affect the apparent responsiveness of API calls just because it took a moment for node.js to get around to processing the waiting responses.

There are tools that monitor the responsiveness of your own http server on a continual basis (you can set whatever monitoring interval you want). If you have a CPU-hog somewhere, those tools would show a similar lag in responsiveness. There are also tools that monitor the health of your network connection which would also show a connectivity glitch. These are the types of monitoring tools that people whose job it is to maintain a healthy server farm might use. I don't have a name handy for either one, but you can presumably find such tools by searching.